# Как правильно описать тип данных для объекта в typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть такой объект:

```
[
    {
        login: {
            min: 6
        }
    }
    ,
    {
        password: {
            min: 6,
            max: 10
        }
    }
]
```

Так он передается в метод: `validateSize([{login: {min: 6}}, {password: {min: 6}}])`

Как должно выглядеть описание типа?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, интересует тип массива длины два, с элементами разных типов. Это называется [`tuple`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), и объявляется так:

```
let object: [firstType, secondType] = ...
```

Конкретно для вашего случая:

```
let object: [Login, Password] = [
    {
        login: {
            min: 6
        }
    },
    {
        password: {
            min: 6,
            max: 10
        }
    }
];

class LoginRestriction {
    min: number;
}

class Login {
    login: LoginRestriction;
}

class PasswordRestriction {
    min: number;
    max: number;
}

class Password {
    password: PasswordRestriction;
}

function f(object: [Login, Password]) {
    let login: Login = object[0];
    let password: Password = object[1];
    console.log(login.login.min)
    console.log(password.password.min)
}
```

Comment: тогда уж до конца использовать надо было: `let [login, password] = object`

Comment: или [даже так](https://goo.gl/oBywe2)

Comment: может быть я не корректно описал случай, login и password - это переменные величины имеется ввиду

Comment: @sanu0074 тогда скорее всего никак, разве что `any` использовать. А формат нельзя изменить?

Comment: @diraria к сожалению нет

Comment: @sanu0074, а как происходит валидация, `any` не подойдёт?

Comment: Подойдет, я просто хотел сделать все красиво)